# Filemaker 17 isn't the default the opener script opens if you have older versions installed

Tags: filemaker

Good morning.

I am having issues after deploying Filemaker client 17 to domain workstations. Users have an opener script they use to open up Filemaker Server databases. Even after Filemaker client 17 is installed the opener script still uses the older clients that are still installed on the workstation.

In the past I believe you could fix it via the registry, changing where ".fmp12" pointed to, but that doesn't seem to work anymore. I have gone through every registry key I can find and manually changed the associations etc. But the opener script still opens the old version. Even after uninstalling the old version (in this case 15.3) the opener script started reinstalling it when I ran it.

Is there some way to force the opener script to open the newest version of the Filemaker client?

Thanks all,

Matthew Storr

Comment: This is windows 10.I don't see Filemaker URL under "Choose default apps by protocol". Under "Choose default apps by file type" there is a few Filemaker file types, and I should of mentioned this too, but while the older versions of Filemaker client is installed the only options for opening the Filemaker file types are the old client, WIndows 10 won't even let you browse to the new client path anymore. Its not until I messed with the registry that I could even select Filemaker client 17 there. But EVEN THEN, it still doesn't work. Can't see Filemaker URL anywhere?

Comment: Why Does Windows 10 not have the option to manually browse and select which apps open which file types now? It used to. Off topic rant but Windows 8.1 was a million times better than Windows 10. I am thinking about installing Windows 8.1 and testing there because it is more likely to work on that OS than this extraordinary mess we call Windows 10.